# how do I link files in a folder?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I tried this:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/scripts/SyntaxHighlighter.css"></link>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.css">
```

It didn't even load because I tried using one of bootstraps components and didn't work. I'm not trying this on xampp or wampp or anything i'm doing this without any webserver. Help?

Comment: If you want to use Bootstrap components you need to include `bootstrap.js` too

Comment: Since we are not aware of the folder structure of your local machine, we cannot possibly answer this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on where the current file in question is placed in your folder structure.

Since you're not using a local web server like xampp or wampp, you probably shouldn't be using "**/**" at the beginning of your `href`.

The "**/**" at the beginning will look at the root of your folder, so in this case it'll probably look back to `C:/`  if you're using windows.

Remove the beginning **"/"** and then traverse through the folders relative to the current file your are sourcing them from. If you need to go **up one level**, use "**../**" to go up on folder level.

For example:

If you were starting in `C:/www/file.html`

and you wanted to link a source to `C:/www/scripts/SyntaxHighlighter.css`

Your link would look like this:

`<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="scripts/SyntaxHighlighter.css">`

If you were starting in `C:/www/folder/file.html`

Your link would look like this:

`<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../scripts/SyntaxHighlighter.css">`

Comment: Quick note: If you were using a local server like xampp or wamp, then "**/**" which points to the root folder, will point to your **web root** folder - the folder you put your web files in to get your website to display. On apache the web root folder is usually that **www** folder.

Answer (score 0):

```
<head>  
<title></title>  
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">  
<!-- Bootstrap -->  
<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
```

- See more at: http://www.w3resource.com/twitter-bootstrap/tutorial.php#sthash.clYJB2Wm.dpuf

You must have your doc HTML5 to use bootstrap flawlesslssly